# SQLite создание базы данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Пытаюсь сделать бд в приложении андройд, создается сама база данных, а полей в ней нет! 
Прикладываю код

```
public static final String id = "id";
public static final String FIO = "FIO";
public static final String time = "time";
public DataBase(Context context)
{
    super(context,Database,null,1 );
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + FIO + " TEXT)");
}
```

Comment: Как вы поняли что полей нет?

Comment: Просто когда смотрел в DB BROWSER копировал с устройства один из трех файлов БД, при копировании трех все отлично)

Comment: После TEXT) , но перед кавычками нужна ";"

Comment: @НикитаИванов, это означает, что Вы не закрыли базу и поэтому SQLite не перенесла данные из журналов (дополнительных файлов) в основной файл. Но они никуда не потеряются, если Вы не удалите сами файлы, естественно.